# Idle session timeout for MobileFirst platform 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have an X-code app integrated with Mobile first platform 7.0. I want to implement idle session timeout for the app. I have tried two scenarios to resolve this issue.
First I have added below line in **server.xml**

```
<httpSession invalidationTimeout="10m" />
```

Second I have added below line in **worklight.properties**

```
serverSessionTimeout=10
```

I am still not getting time out after being idle for more than 10 mins.
What am I missing?

Comment: Is this a native application? Is your application protected by a securitytest ?If so, after 10 mins , are you not challenged again if you make a server request?

Comment: @VivinK yeah the application is native and after 10 minutes, it is again calling the security challenge. In this situation what I actually wants that App should log out but instead it gets success response from security challenge and logged in again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `serverSessionTimeout` property is a *server* property. Meaning that the session expires in the server and if the *client* attempts to connect to the server after the set expiration time, then the client will act accordingly.

If you have a security challenge in place, then once the expiration took place, the challenge would've been invoked (once the client attempts to connect the server). Otherwise, you cannot detect this through this property.

What you can do, is set a "timer" on the client side that runs and counts until the session time has met, and do some logic based on it. This of course solely depends on what your required scenario is.

Comment: my required scenario is that App should logged out but instead it is getting success response from security challenge and starts calling APIs. Is there anything that can be done from server side to make this happen?

Comment: Again, if the timeout has expired and there is a request from the client to the server after that expiration, then the server will send a challenge to the client. It is your responsibility in the handle challenge code in your application, to display the login screen, if that's what you want to do. Review the authentication tutorials.